# Are positive, comparative, and superlative degrees properties of forms or adjective words?

Tags: adjectives, comparative-degree

In Latin, [it seems to me](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/20846/1100) that an adjective word can have several forms, varying across number, case, and gender. That is, number, case, and gender are properties of forms, not properties of adjective words. Positive, comparative, and superlative degrees are, however, not properties of forms but properties of adjective words.

In English, are positive, comparative, and superlative degrees properties of forms or adjective words? For example, are long, longer, and longest three different adjective words, or three forms of the same adjective word? How about good, better, and best?

Thanks.

Comment: Another very interesting question which doesn't appear to be about learning English, as much as categorizing it, which is the domain of [linguistics.se], or [english.se].